# Access For each root atrribute in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xhtml

I am trying to access the for each node attribute using xslt. But It didn't work. need to print shrui value for each hotelroom. can any one help me on this???I

Below is My XML Response.

```
   <HotelRoom SHRUI="AqZE8Cw72fDfNL6X0hqQTQ==" availCount="10" onRequest="N">
              <Board type="SIMPLE" code="BB-E10" shortname="BB">BED AND BREAKFAST</Board>
              <RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="SGL-E10" characteristic="ST">SINGLE STANDARD</RoomType>
              <Price>
                <Amount>549.360</Amount>
              </Price>
            </HotelRoom>
```

Below is My XSLT.

```
  <xsl:for-each select="hm:HotelRoom ">
                <shrui>
                  <xsl:value-of select="hm:HotelRoom/@SHRUI"/>
                </shrui>
                <board>
                  <xsl:value-of select="hm:Board"/>
                </board>
                <roomtype>
                  <xsl:value-of select="hm:RoomType"/>
                </roomtype>
                <roomcode>
                  <xsl:value-of select="hm:RoomType/@code"/>
                </roomcode>
                <boardcode>
                  <xsl:value-of select="hm:Board/@code"/>
                </boardcode>
                <xsl:for-each select="hm:Price ">
                  <amount>
                    <xsl:value-of select="hm:Amount"/>
                  </amount>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace...

```
<xsl:value-of select="hm:HotelRoom/@SHRUI"/>
```

...with...

```
<xsl:value-of select="@SHRUI"/>
```

Also, by the looks of it, you could benefit from a more push style of design (refer: http://www.eddiewelker.com/2008/11/25/push-style-xslt-vs-pull-style/ and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xdpshpul.html)

Comment: +1 for teaching me the terms push- and pull- XSLT! I've tried to encourage people not to write pull-XSLTs but could never find the right term.